# Как запретить запоминание положения страницы браузером, чтобы анимация меню не выполнялась автоматически?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

На странице есть меню со свойством `transition: height 0.2s ease-in-out;`.

Если прокрутить страницу вниз, то высота меню меняется. Но, если обновить страницу, если мы уже её прокрутили, то меню сразу сворачивается. Можно ли как-то запретить браузера запоминать положение страницы, чтобы она открывалась с самого начала?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно после загрузки страниц прокрутить её вверх.

```
window.scrollTo(0,0)
```

Но так скорее всего не сработает, так как по моему опыту он прокрутку делает уже после загрузки скриптов, поэтому делает так.

```
setTimeout("window.scrollTo(0,0)",0)
```

Трюк c `setTimeout` позволяет запустить скрол уже после отработки скриптов.